# Which object does name "g" bind to?

Tags: python, python-3.x

The below assignment is taken from [here](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/%7Ecs61a/fa12/hw/hw4.html):

> Q5. Define the repeated function from Homework 2 by calling reduce with compose1 as the first argument. Add only a single expression to the starter implementation below:

```
def square(x):
    return x*x

def compose1(f, g):
    """Return a function of x that computes f(g(x))."""
    return lambda x: f(g(x))

from functools import reduce

def repeated(f, n):
    """Return the function that computes the nth application of f, for n>=1.

    f -- a function that takes one argument
    n -- a positive integer

    >>> repeated(square, 2)(5)
    625
    >>> repeated(square, 4)(5)
    152587890625
    """
    assert type(n) == int and n > 0, "Bad n"
    return reduce(compose1, "*** YOUR CODE HERE ***" )
```

To complete this assignment, I would like to understand, to what does `g` bind to? `f` binds to the `square` function.

Comment: Do you know what [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) does? Here's a hint: if you want to return a function that does `f(f(f(…f(arg)))))`, that's going to be `compose(f, compose(f, compose(f, …(f))))`. Does that tell you what `g` is going to be?

Comment: g can be any inbuilt python function

Comment: @sachinsaxena: So? That's true, but in the OP's case, it never _will_ be a built-in function…

Comment: why -1 for this question?

Comment: My guess is that someone didn't read carefully, and thought you were asking them to just solve the assignment for you (which would deserve a downvote), instead of help you understand what the `g` arguments are to each `compose1` call so you could solve the assignment yourself (which I don't think deserves a downvote). That's always a risk in questions like these. I'm not sure how to write things carefully so that nobody gets the wrong impression from a quick scan, but that's what you have to figure out if you're concerned about the votes.

Comment: I agree with abarnet: this question is in the close vote queue for "unclear what you are asking", but it's actually perfectly clear what is being asked.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, what should `repeated(f, 4)` return?

A function that, when called on some arbitrary `arg`, will return `f(f(f(f(arg))))`.

So, if you want to build that with `compose1`, you'll need to return either `compose1(compose1(compose1(f, f), f), f)` or `compose1(f, compose1(f, compose1(f, f)))`.

Now, look at what [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) does, and figure out what it's going to pass to `compose1` each time. Clearly your `iterable` argument has to either start or end with `f` itself. But what else do you want there to make sure you get one of the two acceptable results?

And meanwhile, inside each call to `compose1` except the last, one of the two arguments has to be the `repeated` function's `f`, while the other will be the result of another call to `compose1`. (The last time, of course, they'll both be `f`.) Figure out which of those is `f` and which is `g`, and how you get `reduce` to pass the right values for each, and you've solved the problem.

Comment: `return reduce(compose1, [f for i in range(n)])`

Comment: @overexchange: Yeah, that's the answer to your assignment. So I assume you also know the answer to your question of what `g` is inside each `compose1` call?

Comment: g is f, everytime you call compose1